# rand and rands implementation in python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, random

I need an implementation of rand and rands from c++ in python to re-encrypt a bunch of files. But can't seem to get it right.

I have a exe that un-encrypts a file into text, I also have to source code, after editing the file I need to encrypt it using the same method.

Since I don't know how to write c++ code, I opted to write in python. Trying first to decrypt it to know the method is the same.

---

The following code is the c++ code that un-encrypted the files, where "buff" is the beginning of the encrypted block and "len" length of said block.

```cpp
static const char KEY[] = "KF4QHcm2";
static const unsigned long KEY_LEN = sizeof(KEY) - 1;

void unobfuscate(unsigned char* buff, unsigned long len) {
  srand((char)buff[len - 1]);

  for (unsigned long i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 2) {
    buff[i] ^= KEY[rand() % KEY_LEN];
  }
}
```

From what I understand it takes the last character of the encrypted block as the seed, and from the beginning every 2 bytes it xors the value with an element of the KEY array, this index is determined by the remainder of a random number divided by the KEY length.

Searching around the web, I find that c++ uses a simple [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) that shouldn't be used for encryption, but can't seem to make it work.

I found [one example of the code](https://gist.github.com/wbowling/e20b6cd096d480d623462632b4ba0329) and tried to implement the other but either don't seem to work.

```py
#My try at implementing it
def rand():
  global seed
  seed = (((seed * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7FFFFFFF)

  return seed
```

I also read that the rand function is between 0 and RAND_MAX, but can't find the value of RAND_MAX, if I found it maybe random.randrange() could be used.

It can also be the way I set the seed since it seems in c++ a char works but in python I'm setting it to the value of the character.

Here is what I observe when un-encrypting the file using the various methods. This is just the first 13 bytes, so if someone needs to check if it works it is possible to do so.

```
The block ends with the sequence: 4C 0A 54 C4 this means C4 is the seed
Example encrypted:
77 43 35 69 26 6B 0C 6E 3A 74 4B 33 71     wC5i&k.n:tK3q
Example un-encrypted using c++:
24 43 6C 69 63 6B 49 6E 69 74 0A 33 34     $ClickInit.34
Example un-encrypted using python example:
1A 43 7E 69 77 6B 38 6E 0E 74 1A 33 3A     .C~iwk8n.t.3:
Example un-encrypted using python implementation:
3C 43 73 69 6E 6B 4A 6E 0E 74 1A 33 37     <CsinkJn.t.37
```

I can also have something wrong in my python script, so here is the file in case it has any errors:

```py
import os

def srand(s):
  global seed
  seed = s

def rand():
    global seed
    #Example code
    #seed = (seed * 214013 + 2531011) % 2**64

    #return (seed >> 16)&0x7fff

    #Implementation code
    seed = (((seed * 1103515245) + 12345) & 0x7FFFFFFF)

    return seed

KEY = ['K','F','4','Q','H','c','m','2']
KEY_LEN = len(KEY) - 1

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".dat"):
        print("    Decoding " + filename)

        #open file
        file = open(filename, "rb")

        #set file attributes
        file_length = os.path.getsize(filename)
        file_buffer = [0] * file_length

        #copy contents of file to array
        for i in range(file_length):
            file_buffer[i] = int.from_bytes(file.read(1), 'big')

        #close file
        file.close()

        print("    Random Seed: " + chr(file_buffer[-1]))

        #set random generator seed
        srand(file_buffer[-1])

        #decrypt the file
        for i in range(3600, file_length, 2):
            file_buffer[i] ^= ord(KEY[rand() % KEY_LEN])

        #print to check if output is un-encrypted
        for i in range(3600, 3613, 1):
            print(file_buffer[i])
            print(chr(file_buffer[i]))

        continue
    else:
        #Do not try to un-encrypt the python script
        print("/!\ Can't decode " + filename)
    continue
```

---

If anyone can help me figure this out I would be grateful, if possible I would love this to work in python but, from what I can gather, it seems like I will have to learn c++ to get it to work.

Comment: `rand` in C++ is basically an implementation defined function.  If you want the code to be portable I'd suggest using something like a messner twister (`std::mt19937`)

Comment: @NathanOliver -- s/messner/mersenne/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand` is not a cryptographic function.

`rand`'s algorithm is not stable between systems compilers or anything else.

If you have no choice, your best bet is to use python-C/C++ interoperability techniques and actually run `rand()` and `srand()`.  That will suck, but it will suck as much as the original code did.